# How to get original payload body in except block after raise_for_status is called()

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a python web server endpoint that calls an external API

```
        try:
            resp = requests.post(
                url,
                json={...},
            )
            resp.raise_for_status()
            resp_result = resp.json()

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
            print(e)
            err_msg = str(e)
            resp_result = {"error": err_msg}

        return JSONResponse(resp_result)
```

The issue is that when the API I call returns a 400, it goes into the `except` block as expected, but then the returned error message isn't the complete error message that the external API returned.

When the external API fails, it returns a 400 with a body like this

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "API key invalid",
        "type": "invalid_request_error",
        "param": null,
        "code": null
    }
}
```

But when I do `print(e)`, all I get is

`400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://X`

But I want to return the full external API error message to caller of my endpoint here. So how do I get the full error body while in the except block?
Do I need to not use raise_for_status if I want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As commented by Rasen58, the response will be out of scope once the try block fails and the except block executes. This means you will not be able to access the APIs error message in the except block. What you can do, is check the status code, and return the error if its a 400:

```
try:
    resp = requests.post(
        url,
        json={...},
    )

    if resp.status_code in [400, 404]: 
       # handle it accordingly, e.g. print the API response: 
       print(resp.json())
       return

    resp.raise_for_status()
    resp_result = resp.json()


except Exception as e:
    # handle the exception
```

Comment: How are you going to call `resp.json()` in the error block? `resp` isn't in scope there